# I get "can't find the quote item" when I add something to cart...why?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I get

> "can't find the quote item"

when I add something to **cart**, and then edit it again. I have seen this issue on both chrome, IE, and safari for the site in question, across devices and ISPs. I was able to capture the source code and errors for this happening in the product page, the cart, and a variation on chrome last week. Below I have shared view-only google docs that will allow you to see the code, screenshots of what the issue looks like, and the error that shows up on the page. I have highlighted the section of code that i THINK is the culprit, but please note I am not a coder, so the code below might not be the culprit. The google docs are like 70 pages each but I didn't want to leave anything out. :)

Product Page Error Code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1n_6_ilrpQFIb_g_4J9Vu-F3s0Jfm-pKDCDrc5P9_9ng/edit?usp=sharing

Product Page red Error Code AND green OK:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pc1wWeKKamBFE3oyAyTlBvPjdMrNibsFe-jAEHbYye4/edit?usp=sharing

Cart Error Code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wYjCbWgBVzcIsZdLy0MQPDuCou3CMr61Tztt0HFEslE/edit?usp=sharing

No issue in the cart: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nvxdoOL-Q_HyoZ9qmYu_DDFmluzYSDLJYYfGLKVf-XU/edit?usp=sharing